# C String Becomes Null

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv

I am learning how to get arguments in C, however, when I run the code below with the following input, the first one becomes null.

Input: `./a.out a b c d e f g h i j k`

Output: `(null) b c d e f g h i j k`

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int i = 2, j = 0;
        char *foo = argv[1];
        char *bar[10];
        while(j < 10 && i < argc)
        {
            bar[j++] = argv[i++];
        }
        bar[j] = NULL;

        printf("%s ", foo);
        for(j = 0; bar[j] != NULL; j++)
        {
            printf("%s ", bar[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a question? When j == 10, you assign to b[ 10 ], but b is only of size 10 so you are assigning beyond the bounds of b.

Comment: Note that the behavior of passing a null pointer with a `"%s"` format is undefined.  Your implementation happens to be friendly enough to print `"(null)"`; others won't necessarily do that.

Comment: In my settings (visual studio 2010), it worked. But @WilliamPursell is right, address of foo might be just after bar, so bar[10] points to foo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of the loop you write `NULL` to `bar[10]`, but you have only allocated `bar[0 - 9]`. That probably overwrites `foo`.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to set the end of the array to NULL. Would I then need to allocate 11 for the array or?

Comment: Yes, if you put a sentinel value at the end, you have to allocate an extra space for it.

Answer (score 4):

You're setting bar[10] to NULL at the end of the loop, but it only goes up to bar[9]. Since foo is allocated just after bar on the stack, bar[10]=NULL overwrites foo instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try

while( --argc ) puts( *++argv );